# How do I loop exporting multiple tables to flat files (csv) in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a SQL database with 4 tables in SSMS 2017.

Currently I am exorting them one by one using Right Click > Tasks > Export data and following the pop-up boxes in SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Anyone know if I can write a query to loop the export of all of them to different named files?

Comment: What's the names of your tables

Comment: dbo.x1; dbo.x2; dbo.x3; dbo.x4

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous way to export data from SQL Server, please see most(if not all) of the options here - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Export/147145/

I would personally go with automating it true PowerShell, below you can see how to export it for a single table:

Run in PowerShell:

```
Import-Module SQLPS
$SQLCommand = “SELECT * FROM [AdventureWorks].[Production].[Products]”
Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $SQLCommand | Export-Csv -Path C:\Export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You can of course work to automate it, prepare a list of the tables you need and go with a for each loop true all of them.